# SDL 1.2 and SMPEG: Black and white video output only

Tags: c++, sdl, dev-c++, mpeg, sdl-1.2

When trying to port SMPEG to SDL 1.2, I used SDL_CreateRGBSurface instead of SDL_UpdateTexture. In the end, however, I came up with this:

`front=SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(context.frame->image,context.frame->w,   context.frame->h,8,context.frame->w,0xff,0xff,0xff,0);`

And this worked, but I got a black and white image instead of a coloured one. 
Any tinkering of the bpp had some crazy results.
Could I have a tip or some sample code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently you have to use an SDL_YUVOverlay. Memcpy the frame's pixel data (double the number of pixels for the amount of bytes) into the overlay and then update the surface.

I think I got SMPEG in the bag now.